# Create/override variables in Magento 2 theme

Tags: magento, magento2

Which is correct to override existing and/or create new less variables in magento 2?

In my custom theme under:

- `web/css/source/_variables.less`

or

- `web/css/source/_theme.less`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's depend on use of variable :

If you are working with variables that are meant to be used across **multiple themes**, use _variables.less,

If the variables are specific to the styling of a **particular theme only**, use _theme.less.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).